# App site with reliable ratings + comments?

Tags: applications, app-ratings

While Android Enthusiasts is nice, it's still a very small site.

I need to find some applications for Android smartphones, and was wondering where people went for ratings + reliable comments from users? PlayStore? Other?

Incidently, I need to find two applications for a friend who wants to study English and Chinese, but don't know where to go to find the best apps for this.

Thank you.

Comment: + Android Enthusiasts is per FAQ no App rating and  suggesting site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll reliable is somewhat subjective. But I can recommend [App Brain](http://www.appbrain.com/) ([Play Store App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps)) and [App Aware](http://appaware.com/) ([Play Store App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appaware)).

App Brain provides some additional features compared to the Play Store and App Aware allows you to follow app streams based on a topic (games, sw development, etc.). Both try to suggest you apps based on the apps that you have installed. And both are not a new app market, they just redirect you to the Play Store if you want to install a app.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll see if I can sort through the hundreds of thousand's of applications to find the applications I need.

Comment: Both these apps seem to rely on "crowdsourcing."  Is there a source of reliable editorial reviews?